# how to dynamically set width of table column in css using ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

hi i am working on a UI that has a table in which the column should adjust its width according to percentage provided in data. I am using ng-repeat to get data in table column but don,t have idea how to set the width diffently for each data recieved . this is my angular js code

```js
var App = angular.module("myApp", []);
App.controller("maincontroller",function($scope){
 $scope.info=[
 {name:'aob',
 number:20%},
{name:'cc',
number:15%},
 {name:'mb',
 number:20%},
{name:'ts',
number:6%},
 {name:'ws',
 number:8%},
{name:'t',
number:8%},
 {name:'aob',
 number:2%},
  {name:'pb',
  number:25%}
  
 ]


 
}
);
```

and this is my html in which i need to insert data the first table is dynamic with angularjs rest all are hard coded..

```js
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>UI</title>

<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
 
</head>
<body style="background-color:#F2F2F2" ng-controller="maincontroller" >


<div class="first">
<div class="container">

<table>
<tr >

</tr>
</table>

<table>

<tbody>


<tr>
<div class="get">
<h4>Station</h4><p>HKG</p><h4>Airline Operator</h4><p>Y7</p><h4>Aircraft Model</h4><p>A300-600F</p><h4>Configuration Class</h4><p>Cargo</p><h4>Service Type</h4><p>Transit</p>
</div>

<th id="cool"><img src="pic4.png" height="50px" width="50px" padding-top="50px">TTS142</th>

<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" ng-repeat="do in info" ng-style="set_color(do)">

<a href="#" class="link">{{do.name}}</a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
<th id="cool"><img src="pic3.png" height="50px" width="50px" padding-top="50px">TTS142</th>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table >  
<tr>
<div class="get">
<h4>Station</h4><p>HKG</p><h4>Airline Operator</h4><p>Y7</p><h4>Aircraft Model</h4><p>A300-600F</p><h4>Configuration Class</h4><p>Cargo</p><h4>Service Type</h4><p>Transit</p>
</div>

<th id="cool"><img src="pic4.png" height="50px" width="50px" padding-top="50px">TTS143</th>

<td bgcolor="#FF3300" style="width:8.5%">
<a href="#" class="link">LT</a>
<div class="tooltip">sorry for the delay</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#FF3300" style="width:5.7%">
<a href="#" class="link">AOB</a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:2.8%"><a href="#" class="link">CC </a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:11.4%"><a href="#" class="link">MB</a>
<div class="tooltip">lets maintain it</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:14.2%"><a href="#" class="link">TS</a>
<div class="tooltip">we are on time ladies and gentleman</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:10%"><a href="#" class="link">WS</a>
<div class="tooltip">hi whats up</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:4.2%"><a href="#" class="link">R</a>
<div class="tooltip">sorry for the dealy</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#66FF66" style="width:8.5%">
<a href="#" class="link">LT</a>
<div class="tooltip">sorry for the delay</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#66FF66" style="width:2.8%"><a href="#" class="link">AOB</a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#66FF66" style="width:25.7%"><a href="#" class="link">PB</a>
<div class="tooltip">lets maintain it</div></td> 
<th id="cool"><img src="pic3.png" height="50px" width="50px" padding-top="50px">TTS143</th>
</tr>
</table>
<table >  
<tr>
<div class="get">
<h4>Station</h4><p>HKG</p><h4>Airline Operator</h4><p>Y7</p><h4>Aircraft Model</h4><p>A300-600F</p><h4>Configuration Class</h4><p>Cargo</p><h4>Service Type</h4><p>Transit</p>
</div>

<th id="cool"><img src="pic4.png" height="50px" width="50px" padding-top="50px">TTS168</th>

<td bgcolor="#FF3300" style="width:8.5%">
<a href="#" class="link">AOB</a>
<div class="tooltip">sorry for the delay</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:5.7%">
<a href="#" class="link">Cabin Cleaning</a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:11.4%"><a href="#" class="link">Maintenance Block</a>
<div class="tooltip">lets maintain it</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:14.2%"><a href="#" class="link">Toilet Servicing</a>
<div class="tooltip">we are on time ladies and gentleman</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:10%"><a href="#" class="link">Water Servicing</a>
<div class="tooltip">hi whats up</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:4.2%"><a href="#" class="link">Refuelling</a>
<div class="tooltip">sorry for the dealy</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#66FF66" style="width:2.8%"><a href="#" class="link">Aircraft off Block </a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#66FF66" style="width:25.7%"><a href="#" class="link">Push Back</a>
<div class="tooltip">lets maintain it</div></td> 
<th id="cool"><img src="pic3.png" height="50px" width="50px" padding-top="50px">TTS168</th>
</tr>
</table>
<table >  
<tr>
<div class="get">
<h4>Station</h4><p>HKG</p><h4>Airline Operator</h4><p>Y7</p><h4>Aircraft Model</h4><p>A300-600F</p><h4>Configuration Class</h4><p>Cargo</p><h4>Service Type</h4><p>Transit</p>
</div>

<th id="cool"><img src="pic4.png" height="50px" width="50px" padding-top="50px">TTS182</th>

<td bgcolor="#FF3300" style="width:14.5%">
<a href="#" class="link">aircraft on block</a>
<div class="tooltip">sorry for the delay</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:8.7%">
<a href="#" class="link">Cabin Cleaning</a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:21.4%"><a href="#" class="link">Maintenance Block</a>
<div class="tooltip">lets maintain it</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:20.2%"><a href="#" class="link">Toilet Servicing</a>
<div class="tooltip">we are on time ladies and gentleman</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="##66FF66" style="width:10%"><a href="#" class="link">Water Servicing</a>
<div class="tooltip">hi whats up</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#66FF66" style="width:14.2%"><a href="#" class="link">Refuelling</a>
<div class="tooltip">sorry for the dealy</div></td>

<th id="cool"><img src="pic3.png" height="50px" width="50px" padding-top="50px">TTS182</th>
</tr>
</table>
<div>
<ul class="legend">
    <li><span class="arrival"></span>Arrival</li>
    <li><span class="Groundhandling"></span>Ground handling</li>
    <li><span class="Departure"></span> Departure</li>
   
</ul>
<div>
<a href="#" class="link1">legend codes</a>
<div class="tooltip1">
<table>
<tr>AOB - Aircraft on block</tr>
<br>
<tr>CC - Cabin cleaning</tr>
<br>
<tr>MB - Maintenance Block</tr>
<br>
<tr>TS - Toilet Servicing</tr>
<br>
<tr>WS - Water Servicing</tr>
<br>
<tr>R - Refulleing</tr>
<br>
<tr>PB - Push back</tr>
<br>
<tr>LT - Long Towing-Arrival to Parking</tr>
</table></div></div></div>


</div>
</div>
<div class="second">
<div class="container">
<div class="get">
<h4>Station</h4>
<p>HKG</p>
<h4>Airline OPerator</h4>
<p>Y7</p>
<h4>Aircraft Model</h4>
<P>A300-600F</p>
<h4>Configuration Class</h4>
<p>Cargo</p>
<h4>Service type</h4>
<p>Transit</p>
</div>
<table style="width:100%">  
<tr >
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:8.5%">
<a href="#" class="link">AOB</a>
<div class="tooltip">sorry for the delay</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:5.7%">
<a href="#" class="link">CC</a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:11.4%"><a href="#" class="link">MB</a>
<div class="tooltip">lets maintain it</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:14.2%"><a href="#" class="link">TS</a>
<div class="tooltip">we are on time ladies and gentleman</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:10%"><a href="#" class="link">WS</a>
<div class="tooltip">hi whats up</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:4.2%"><a href="#" class="link">R</a>
<div class="tooltip">sorry for the dealy</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00CCFF" style="width:2.8%"><a href="#" class="link">Aircraft off Block </a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00CCFF" style="width:25.7%"><a href="#" class="link">PB</a>
<div class="tooltip">lets maintain it</div></td> 

</tr>
</table>
<table >  
<tr>
<td style="width:2.8%" bgcolor="#00FFFF">
<a href="#" class="link">AOB</a>
<div class="tooltip">hi whats up</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:8.5%">
<a href="#" class="link">AOB</a>
<div class="tooltip">sorry for the delay</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:5.7%">
<a href="#" class="link">CC</a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00CCFF" style="width:11.4%"><a href="#" class="link">MB</a>
<div class="tooltip">lets maintain it</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#aaaaaa" style="width:14.2%"><a href="#" class="link">TS</a>
<div class="tooltip">we are on time ladies and gentleman</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:10%"><a href="#" class="link">WS</a>
<div class="tooltip">hi whats up</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:4.2%"><a href="#" class="link">R</a>
<div class="tooltip">sorry for the dealy</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:2.8%"><a href="#" class="link">Aircraft off Block </a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00CCFF" style="width:25.7%"><a href="#" class="link">PB</a>
<div class="tooltip">lets maintain it</div></td> 

</tr>
</table>
<table >  
<tr >
<td style="width:2.8%" bgcolor="#00FFFF">
<a href="#" class="link">AOB</a>
<div class="tooltip">hi whats up</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:8.5%">
<a href="#" class="link">AOB</a>
<div class="tooltip">sorry for the delay</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:5.7%">
<a href="#" class="link">CC</a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00CCFF" style="width:11.4%"><a href="#" class="link">MB</a>
<div class="tooltip">lets maintain it</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#aaaaaa" style="width:14.2%"><a href="#" class="link">TS</a>
<div class="tooltip">we are on time ladies and gentleman</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:10%"><a href="#" class="link">WS</a>
<div class="tooltip">hi whats up</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:4.2%"><a href="#" class="link">R</a>
<div class="tooltip">sorry for the dealy</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:2.8%"><a href="#" class="link">Aircraft off Block </a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00CCFF" style="width:25.7%"><a href="#" class="link">PB</a>
<div class="tooltip">lets maintain it</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#aaaaaa" style="width:7.14%"><a href="#" class="link">on time</a>
<div class="tooltip">we are on time ladies and gentleman</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#aaaaaa" style="width:7.14%"><a href="#" class="link">scheduled </a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table >  
<tr >
<td style="width:2.8%" bgcolor="#00FFFF">
<a href="#" class="link">AOB</a>
<div class="tooltip">hi whats up</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:8.5%">
<a href="#" class="link">AOB</a>
<div class="tooltip">sorry for the delay</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:5.7%">
<a href="#" class="link">CC</a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00CCFF" style="width:11.4%"><a href="#" class="link">MB</a>
<div class="tooltip">lets maintain it</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#aaaaaa" style="width:14.2%"><a href="#" class="link">TS</a>
<div class="tooltip">we are on time ladies and gentleman</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:10%"><a href="#" class="link">WS</a>
<div class="tooltip">hi whats up</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:4.2%"><a href="#" class="link">R</a>
<div class="tooltip">sorry for the dealy</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:2.8%"><a href="#" class="link">Aircraft off Block </a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00CCFF" style="width:25.7%"><a href="#" class="link">PB</a>
<div class="tooltip">lets maintain it</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#aaaaaa" style="width:7.14%"><a href="#" class="link">on time</a>
<div class="tooltip">we are on time ladies and gentleman</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#aaaaaa" style="width:7.14%"><a href="#" class="link">scheduled </a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>  
<tr >
<td style="width:2.8%" bgcolor="#00FFFF">
<a href="#" class="link">AOB</a>
<div class="tooltip">hi whats up</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:8.5%">
<a href="#" class="link">AOB</a>
<div class="tooltip">sorry for the delay</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:5.7%">
<a href="#" class="link">CC</a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00CCFF" style="width:11.4%"><a href="#" class="link">MB</a>
<div class="tooltip">lets maintain it</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#aaaaaa" style="width:14.2%"><a href="#" class="link">TS</a>
<div class="tooltip">we are on time ladies and gentleman</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:10%"><a href="#" class="link">WS</a>
<div class="tooltip">hi whats up</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:4.2%"><a href="#" class="link">R</a>
<div class="tooltip">sorry for the dealy</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00FFFF" style="width:2.8%"><a href="#" class="link">Aircraft off Block </a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
<td bgcolor="#00CCFF" style="width:25.7%"><a href="#" class="link">PB</a>
<div class="tooltip">lets maintain it</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#aaaaaa" style="width:7.14%"><a href="#" class="link">on time</a>
<div class="tooltip">we are on time ladies and gentleman</div></td> 
<td bgcolor="#aaaaaa" style="width:7.14%"><a href="#" class="link">scheduled </a>
<div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div></td>
</table>
</div>
<div id="click1">
<a href="#"><img src="pic7.png" width="40px" height="25px"></a></div>

</div>

<div id="click"><a href="#"><img src="pic6.png" width="40px" height="25px"></a></div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest I come is this:

```
    <table ng-repeat="item in items">
    <tr>
        <td width="{{item.value}}"> {{item.name}} </td>
        <td width="{{item.value}}"> {{item.value}} </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Where value can be something like 30% or 70px, or w/e

in my controller all I have is this

```
    $scope.items = [
    {name: 'item1', value: '70%'},
    {name: 'item2', value: '10%'},
    {name: 'item3', value: '20%'}
];
```

Just for testing purpose (dont have same data as you)

Updated answer: I replaced `ng-style=""` with `width=""`

This works for me, but as you stated you can't have the repeat on `<table>` level, but I don't know how else to do it.

Comment: why u have extra colum name for placeholder

Comment: the placeholder is just for reference to see if the width was correct

Comment: its not working actually if i am giving ng-repeat in table tag the table is repeating everytime i want column data to repeat

Comment: I will look into it and update my answer if I come up with anything

Comment: thanks a lot but i was able to do it with ng-style..thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

One idea could be make a directive for columns or rows, how you prefer, that will replace the row or column with custom row or column produced in the directive that have custom width by your criteria. The example refer to one td by it could be transformed as you need. Hope this help.

```
angular.module('appname')
    .directive('tddirective', ['$compile',
        function ($compile) {
            return {
                scope: {
                    item: '='
                },
                replace: true,
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    var html = "";

                    function addElement(html) {
                        var toInsert = angular.element(html);
                        element.append(toInsert);
                        $compile(toInsert)(scope);
                    }

                    //Here you make the validation or what do you want for stablish the correct width, even you can compare with anothers columns and  format the width in any case
                    html = '\
                           <td style="width: " + item.width +";">item.name</td>';
                    addElement(html);
                 }
            }
        }])
```